# How to create an Excel stacked bar chart with two bars, each drawing from different sources?

Tags: excel, stacked-chart

Is it possible to create a stacked bar chart in Excel with two stacked bars, each drawing from separate data, but scaling data the same way?  For example, say I want to show the following revenue from a school in the first bar:

Tuition - $4,000,000 (Blue)
Fund Raising - $170,000 (Green)
Other - $50,000 (Yellow)

The next bar would display under the first and break down tuition into the following components:

Primary - $2,000,000 (Light Green)
Elementary - $1,500,000 (Purple)
Middle School - $500,000 (Orange)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the standard functionality of a stacked bar chart should work.  Primary, Elementary and Middle school would together equal 4000000, so you can add the data labels to a regular stacked bar graph, and the total on the graph would be represented within the slices of the stacked bar graph.  When creating the example I did have to right click and navigate to select data, and then switch the row/column, but if you experiment with it you should get it pretty quickly.
[image]

Comment: This isn't what I am looking for.  Unfortunately, I was unable to upload a graphic to illustrate what I wanted, because I am new to this forum.  I was, however, able to come up with a solution which I will post separately.

Answer (score 0):

After posting my question, I was able to come up with an answer.  It involves "tricking" Excel in to thinking you have two separate bars using blank cells.  To do so, you need three columns, one for the data labels and two for the data in the bars.

Here is the data for each row, with commas separating columns A, B and C:

```
Row 1: <blank>, "Tuition", "Total Revenue"
Row 2: "Tuition",<blank>, 40000000
Row 3: "Fund Raising", <blank>, 170000
Row 4: "Other", <blank>, 50000
Row 5: "Primary", 2000000, <blank>
Row 6: "Elementary", 1500000, <blank>
Row 7: "Middle School", 50000, <blank>
```

After entering the data, select the range a1:c7.  Next click the Insert Tab, then Chart, Bar Chart.  The bar chart will appear.

Last, make sure the "Bar Chart" tabs are shown.  If not, click the chart. Now, click on the Design Tab.  Select "Switch Row/Column" and you should get the chart described in the question.