# Grouping multiple stacked bars on same chart

Tags: excel, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

I'm trying to show 5 stacked bars on the same chart, however for each bar the stacks have different labels. Specifically, I have 5 land areas, each with 5-9 districts. So I'd like 1 bar for each land area and the bar to be segmented by each district they have, and the sizing to be the numerical value for the district.

All the examples I've found (e.g.[tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Nye5NO172A) ) are comparing things which have identical subgroup categories (quarterly performance), and I haven't figured out how to layout my data and incorporate it into the chart to include all the district labels, while keeping them grouped by land area. Any insight would be appreciated

Comment: Perhaps a hand-drawn example of what you want might be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

So referencing this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32399517/how-to-create-an-excel-stacked-bar-chart-with-two-bars-each-drawing-from-differ) I was able to figure it out.
The technique is to have the 5 land areas as column titles, and the rows to be every district, then put in values in the cells which intersect the correct land area and district, leaving every other cell blank. After creating the chart, just switch the row and column labels.